# Keyboard shortcut responds very slow

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, print-screen, responsiveness

The shortcut for print screen became very slow on my Ubuntu 14.04.2. It takes about 10-15 seconds after pressing the key to showing a print screen region selection controls. I tried to use `shutter` as a screenshot tool (`shutter -s -C -e -n -o '/tmp/screenshot.%d-%m-%y.%T.png'`), and assigned a custom shortcut to it, but it didn't change things. When I run the same command in terminal, the app shows instantly. So the problem seems to be in keyboard shortcut system.

Actually, for the sake of testing, I even assigned a shortcut to simple commands like `bash -c 'ls /tmp'` or `gnome-terminal -e 'ls /tmp'`. They still take 10+ seconds to be executed.

On the whole, the system works fast. `Slow keys` setting is turned off. Standard shortcuts work fast. The problem is only with shortcuts for print screen and custom commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After an hour of googling and trying, I've found a workaround to this weird problem. Install and run `CompizConfig Settings Manager`:

```
sudo apt-get install ccsm
ccsm
```

Click `Commands` in `General` category. Ensure the module is activated. Add your custom command on the first tab and set a shortcut on the second one. I set the same command (`shutter` with options) and the same key (`Print`) as I'd set before in "regular" system settings. Now the command began to be run instantly.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS the package is `compizconfig-settings-manager`

Comment: The same solution works for the built-in `gnome-screenshot`

Comment: Thanks. No idea why this problem manifests when things were working fine for so long. I've noticed that it's the custom shortcuts in All Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts that seem affected and noth the others. Glad to have a solution anyway, but would love to know what causes this.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command to kill the service:

```
sudo killall gnome-keyring-daemon
```

The service starts automatically after you killed it, and that fixes the shortcut delay issue until reboot.